# Add dependency in libbacktrace

Tags: gcc, makefile, openwrt

I'm trying to add a dependency in my Makefile at libbacktrace library.

However, it seems I'm not using the correct syntax for it, I've tried:

```
DEPENDS+= +libbacktrace
```

But receive the following message -

```
Package XXXX is missing dependencies for the following libraries
```

Although the libbacktrace is included in -L (lib) path.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include all relevant code (like where `DEPENDS` is used) and the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a plus sign in a package name, so you probably want this:

```
DEPENDS += libbacktrace
```

Comment: The + is used in openWRT makefile, and is definitely not the issue. just to make sure, I signed DEPENDS += libbacktrace with no change in results.